Get image links from a gallery of Pods Framework in WordPress
My current code for this outputs each image as an img tag in a list, I need only the URL of each image in a list.
Here's my current code:
<?php
$obj = pods( 'pod-name', get_the_id() );

$photos = $obj->field( 'field-name' );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $photos as $photo ) {
    echo '<li>'.pods_image( $photo ).'</li>';
} ?>


Upon googling "pods_image", the second hit already suggests that a function named pods_image_url also appears to exist.

Thanks C3roe, replacing pods_image with pods_image_url did the trick.
